# Compiler returned the `Optional` error after I set the `userInteractionEnabled` for a button which was used in multi-views

Tags: ios, swift

### My Original Requirement:

In order to describe my problem conveniently, I will describe some hypothetic instances variables.

- A `button_1`: `UIButton` put on the `vC_1`: `UIViewController`.
- A `cell_1`: `UICollectionViewControllerCell` , the cell in a instance of `UICollectionViewController`  , is connected with `vC_1` via a `StoryBoard Segue`.
- My requirement: Shifting to the `vC_1` after pressed the specific `Cell`, the `button_1` on the `vC_1` can not be touched, which means the value of `userInteractionEnabled` equal to `true`.

### My Original Code:

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   if let identifier = segue.identifier {
       if identifier == "SegueToCardDetail2" {
           let viewController_1 = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController_1
           viewController_1!.button_1.userInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    }
```

### The Error thrown by complier when I pressed the specific cell:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` occurred in same line with `viewController_1!.button_1.userInteractionEnabled = false`.

And I know its an `Optional` error. Maybe the `viewController_1` did not be created when I pressed the `cell`.

### My Question:

Should I do some modification in the `ViewController_1`'s `viewDidLoad()` or in the `prepareForSegue()`? And how?

### My stupid solution for it:

I can just create a new `ViewController_2` which seems as same as `ViewController_1`. And I will set `userInteractionEnabled` to false in the its 'viewDidLoad()'. But it gonna use more memory.

Comment: First, I would rather use the `if let` pattern instead of your current code, to avoid making your app crash. Second, the unexpected `Optional` might very well be due to the button property of the view controller, and not the view controller itself. And third, I'm not sure it is a great idea to manipulate views from another view controller. After all, it's the role of the view controller you're just creating to manage its own views... You'd better rely on state properties or delegation to address this problem. Not a solution per se, I know, but hopefully a few useful hints...

Comment: @Romain Thanks for answering my question. Firstly, can you tell me which part of code shall be used as 'if let' ? Secondly, it's true thing that button is ViewController's property, but you still need to create a viewController before assigning a value to the button. Right? Thirdly, in my view of point, it's a normal thing to manipulate views from others, like shifting the view after pressed a cell in the TableViewController.

Comment: For your first question, instead of `let viewController_1 = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController_1`, I would write it that way: `if let viewController_1 = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController_1 { ... }`. For the second point, please also check that you have properly linked the button to an `IBOutlet` in your `ViewController_1`. And finally, I still think there is a better way to do it other than directly manipulating views from outside the controller which "owns" the view.

Comment: Thanks for your 1st answer, I'll correct it in case the crash.